# Is there any algorithm that can detect fall of a person accurately using accelerometer and gyroscope in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios7, accelerometer, gyroscope

I want to  know how to detect fall of a person is intentional or un-intentional and accurate result using the iPhone's accelerometer and gyroscope. Is there any algorithm exists which gives the accurate results.

Suggest me with ideas...

Comment: Well a fall will result in a zero vertical measurement of the accelerometer. You could possibly use this?